# Using C# how can I split a text file into multiple files

Tags: c#, file-io, streamreader

How can I split a text file that contains ASCII code SOH and ETX into multiple files?

For exmaple the text file I have named 001234.txt contains the following content:

SOH{ABCDXZY}ETX

SOH{ABCDXZY}ETX

SOH{ABCDXZY}ETX

I would like to split the single text file into multiple text files for each ASCII code that starts with SOH and ends with ETX.

The single text file name should be splitted into 101234.txt , 111234.txt..etc and each contains a single content that starts with SOH and ends with ETX.

### I appreciate any help.

using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

```
namespace ASCII_Split
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var txt = "";
            const char soh = (char)1;
            const char eox = (char)3;
            var count = 1;
            var pathToFile = @"‪‪C:\Temp\00599060.txt";

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(pathToFile))
                txt = sr.ReadToEnd();

            while (txt.Contains(soh))
            {
                var outfil = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToFile), count.ToString("000"), "_fix.txt");
                var eInd = txt.IndexOf(eox);
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(outfil, false))
                {
                    sw.Write(txt.Substring(1, eInd - 1));
                }
                txt = txt.Substring(eInd + 1);
                count++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please comment on Stefan's answer instead of editing your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided by SOH and ETX you mean the respective control characters, this here should get you on your way:

```
var txt = "";
const char soh = (char) 1;
const char eox = (char) 3;
var count = 1;
var pathToFile = @"C:\00_Projects_temp\test.txt";

using (var sr = new StreamReader(pathToFile))
    txt = sr.ReadToEnd();

while (txt.Contains(soh))
{
    var outfil = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToFile), count.ToString("000"), "_test.txt");
    var eInd = txt.IndexOf(eox);
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(outfil, false))
    {
        sw.Write(txt.Substring(1, eInd - 1));
    }
    txt = txt.Substring(eInd + 1);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: After debuging the code I get the following error for the using (var sr = new StreamReader(pathToFile)) saying {"The given path's format is not supported."}

Comment: What error? If you say "the following", something needs to follow... ;-)

Comment: Of course you do. The path is to my testing folder. You need to change that!

Comment: Please check the above code that I am using the path is pointed to correct location with the file name.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)

Comment: Did you use the correct - full - path to the file?? Note: your usage of `Path.GetFileName` with wildcard won't work. Using a full path like I did in this example will.

Comment: I used the full path to the file.

Comment: Is the error still with `using(var sr = new StreamReader...`? Are you mixing this code with your original code in any way? I don't understand how the error could arise if you use the correct path.

Comment: yes the error is still pointing with using(var sr = new StreamReader

Comment: Please do not edit MY response. This is your question. Please edit your question if you wish to provide more info. Make sure the path is correct and the file *exists* you have read/write permission to that location.

Comment: Copy your file to a different location. Best create a separate folder for it. There is some permission issue going on.

Comment: Thanks it worked. How can I get it to split the additional and not the first SOH and ETX ? For example if the SOH AND ETX is greater than 1 then split the rest and not the first.

Comment: This splits ALL of them. Please be more precise. Edit your question with an example and also what you have tried. Please show some effort.

Answer (score 1):

This should more or less do the trick:

```
    //Read all text from file into a string
    var fileContent = File.ReadAllText("001234.txt");

    //split text into array according to a Regex pattern
    var pattern = @"SOH*ETX";
    var splitContent = Regex.Split(fileContent, pattern);

    //counter for file names
    var counter = 10;
    foreach(var content in splitContent)
    {
        //create file and use stream to write to it
        using (var stream = File.Create($"{counter++}1234.txt"))
        {
            var contentAsBytes = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(content);
            stream.Write(contentAsBytes, 0, contentAsBytes.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the asker is referring to ASCII _charaters_ SOH (value 01) and ETX (value 03), not substrings "SOH" and "ETX"

Comment: My bad, but perhaps some of it is still useful.

Comment: Thanks, but I have edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you LocEngineer the program works, I did little change to concatonate the filename with the counter using "+" instead of ",".

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;


namespace ASCII_Split
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var txt = "";
            const char soh = (char)1;
            const char eox = (char)3;
            var count = 1;
            var pathToFile = @"C:\Temp\00599060.txt";

            using (var sr = new StreamReader (pathToFile))
                txt = sr.ReadToEnd();

            if (txt.IndexOf(soh) != txt.LastIndexOf(soh))
            {


                while (txt.Contains(soh))
                {
                    var outfil = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToFile), count.ToString("00") + Path.GetFileName(pathToFile));
                    var eInd = txt.IndexOf(eox);
                    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(outfil, false))
                    {
                        sw.Write(txt.Substring(1, eInd - 1));
                    }
                    txt = txt.Substring(eInd + 1);
                    count++;
                }
                File.Move((pathToFile), (pathToFile) + ".org");
            }
        }
    }
}
```